# Terminal download file from automatic download

Tags: linux, download, wget, tar, curl

I am trying to create a script that automatically installs IntelliJ and other Jetbrain products.
But my problem is that I can't download the newest version without saying which it is.

I create the direct link myself over the version and this link:
"https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2016.3.5.tar.gz"

I wonder if it is possible to download a file form a website which automatically downloads the file with a tool like wget or curl?

The page from where you can download the newest version is:
[Intellij Download](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux)

I hope you can help me!

Comment: I afraid you have to scrap the web page with something like `beautifulsoup` or `scrappy` (these are tools for Python).

Comment: The web server could have a static link that always sends the latest file, if you set it up that way... Or you could download an index of all files on some directory on the server, if it's set up to do that, then find the newest version numbered file (with grep/sed/awk/etc) and then wget that file. Otherwise it's hard to download a specific version number without knowing what it is.